# Can I install a plug on a hard-wired cooktop?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, stove

I have a 30" 5 burner cooktop stove that is hardwired. Due to my requirements, I have to be able to swap it out with another cooktop every once in a while.

I was wondering if it is safe to wire the cooktop to a plug, and install a plug socket in the cabinet so I can swap out the cooktop easy. Is this against any type of code?

---

It is a GE Profile electric stove, not gas, and is located in Montreal, Quebec, Canada

---

As per the GE website, it is 40 Amps/240V

Comment: Is this a gas cooktop, in which case the electrical connection is a low-power (probably only requires a 15 amp circuit and uses only an amp or 2) circuit for ignition? Or is it an electric cooktop that uses 30 or 40 amps, 240v, etc.?

Comment: What are the electrical requirements of the stove?  If you don't know, another way of asking that question is what size breaker is the stove currently protected with?

Comment: A call to your local city building inspector should yield a good answer. Indeed they can be hardwire as it is very common to be installed as such but in a case like yours, it is usually having to meet the current codes which is what can get costly.

Comment: Does your electrical supply have a ground wire?

Comment: Is it on its own dedicated circuit, or is it sharing a circuit with another cooking appliance?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You've provided good information, but (per the above comments) we'll need to know more in order to help you. Please edit the new information into your question, so that it'll be easier to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Canadian practice is very similar to US practice.

Stoves and ovens typically live on a 40A or 50A circuit.

It is common to provide receptacles for them, but 40A receptacles are not made, so the (US) National Electrical Code has a special exception allowing 50A receptacles on 40A circuits.

Sometimes the oven and stove are separate, but on the same 40A or 50A circuit, in which the NEC allows two receptacles to be provisioned.